# jQuery Animate and Toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm having a tough time trying to implement a slideToggle event and at the same time implementing an animate feature.

For example, when a user clicks on a button, I'd like the button to move up and then have the div below appear. But when the button is clicked again, I'd like the button to go back to the original space and have the div disappear.

```
$(function() {
    $('.search').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '10px'
    },'slow');

    $('.searchbox').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
    });
});
```

I don't know how or where to put the animate feature to return the .search button back to its original position.

Comment: Have you looked at [http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the callback function

```
$('.search').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '10px'
    },'slow',function(){
        $('.searchbox').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    return false;
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '0px' /*or original value*/
    },'slow',function(){
        $('.searchbox').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This does the same thing as I did before. Unfortunately, though, the .search button doesn't return to it's previous position. The .searchbox DIV is working fine, but I need the button to go back to the original position.

Comment: @user965879 oh! then just use toggle instead of click... I'll edit my answer